# Importação de pacotes dentro de tests com python

Tags: python

Possuo um projeto com a seguinte estrutura:

```
__init__.py
setup.py
- convert_keys/
    - __init__.py
    - convert.py
- tests/
    - test_convert_keys.py
```

Dentro do meu arquivo de `tests` tentei realizar a importação da seguinte maneira;

`from convert_keys import convert`

porém ao tentar executar o arquivo de tests o erro abaixo aparece;

`python tests/test_convert_keys.py`

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "tests/test_convert_keys.py", line 3, in 
>       from convert_keys import convert
>   ImportError: No module named convert_keys

Meu arquivo de tests possui apenas uma classe que herda `unittest.TestCase`, o que esta faltando para que o arquivo dentro de `tests` consiga importar o arquivo em `convert_keys`?

Answer (score 1):

Como não sei como está a estrutura do teu projeto a solução mais simples é você colocar o diretório dele no *path* do **Python**. Você pode fazê-lo de duas maneiras. A primeira é pela variável de ambiente `PYTHONPATH`:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$( pwd )
python tests/test_convert_keys.py
```

A outra, aí alterando teu código, seria acrescentá-lo ao *path* do sistema diretamente de dentro do **Python**.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/tmp/project') # no caso o diretório do teu projeto
from convert_keys import convert
```

Comment: a estrutura é exatamente esta que coloquei na pergunta amigo.

Comment: opa, acabei não sendo claro... falava sobre o conteúdo dos arquivos `__init__.py`, `setup,py` e coisas assim -- redefinição de paths dentro de `setup.py`, definição de como carregar os módulos em `__init__.py` etc.